How do you manage fragment caching invalidation in Rails?
I often use it, but I run into issues when the cached content includes helpers, translations (like date formats or text), etc. like in this example

If the output of a helper changes, the cache doesn't get invalidated unless associated data (e.g., comments) is updated...
The Rails docs suggest adding comments to change the MD5 hash, but that approach feels meh  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#external-dependencies
How do you deal with this? ‍♂️

Please add code as formatted text, not image. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

The image is optional here, so just ignore it if you don't like it @Greg :)

https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. If you want to avoid this question being closed reword it from an open ended question to one that's asking about a concrete answerable problem. And show some respect to the community please.
